# redirect to URL from select2 drop down

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 (https://select2.github.io).

I want use select2 as an live ajax search input.

SO I try make it:

```
var $similar = $(".datajax-items");

$similar.select2({

    placeholder: "search...",
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    ajax: {
           ...
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 20) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; },
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

and functions:

```
function formatRepo(repo) {
if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

var markup = "<a href=\"google.com\" class='select2-result-repository clearfix'></a>";

return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
    return repo.id || repo.text;
}
```

the code works. but when I click on an option (in select box), it (normally) select it. I do not want select it. I want disable selecting and then redirect page to custom URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ifound a simple solution:

declare a variable (for example 'url' in server side (json)) and change code to this:

```
function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
    if(repo.url)  
    {
        window.location.replace(repo.url);
        return 'please wait...';
    } 
    return repo.title || repo.text;
}
```